# Find K Closest pairs in a spatial database (Without specific query object)

Tags: multidimensional-array, spatial, knn, spatial-query, spatial-index

***Input:***

•    **N points {P1, …. , Pn}** -  each point is from the same dimension t:

- Pi = {x_1, …., x_t}  where k is between 18-30 .

•   **Distance function – dist(Pi, Pj)**  - returns a number that is the distance between the points. (The function is a custom function – not a standard Minkowski distance).

***The Problem:***

•   **Main problem:**

- Find the K closest pairs from all the N points – as fast as possible.

•   **Secondary problem:**

- Given a point Q = {x_1, …, x_t} return the K closest pairs.

•   **Nice to Have:**

- A Database where we can add/remove a point Pi and the above queries will run as fast as possible.

***Relevant Data structures:***

•   **KD-TREE**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html

•   **R-TREE**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree
- http://toblerity.org/rtree/

•   **BALL-TREE**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html

***Possible Solutions:***

•   **Main problem:**

- Build a BallTree (sklearn.neighbors.BallTree).
- For every point P in the BallTree find K closest pairs (Now we have N List- where every list contains the K closest pairs for every Point Pi).
- Take the best K pairs from all the list above.

•   **Secondary problem:**

- Build a BallTree (sklearn.neighbors.BallTree).
- Query for closest k pairs for a given point Q.

***Time Complexity So far:***

- For every point in the tree (N in total) find K closest pairs which take O(K*log(N)) - **So in total O(N * K * log(N))**.
- Take the best K pairs from N sorted list - can take **O( Max{ K * log(K),  N } )**. for example with maintaining a min HEAP of size K.

The total complexity, for now, is **O(N * K * log(N))** - can we do better?

Comment: Have you tried something already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Dominik As I mentioned I'm trying to solve the Main problem as fast as possible.

I added a time complexity section, does it helps?

Comment: It sounds more like a Maths problem than a Programming Problem, you may want to ask that on the Maths Stackoverflow Site.

Comment: @Dominik I'll ask there as well, but my intention is to find a faster solution for the above problem that really works - that is why I attached the current data structure I'm using (sklearn.neighbors.BallTree). So, the section of the time analysis is just for intuition - I'm just looking for a solution which will run faster.